# Android splashscreen error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I'm new to android programming. I was trying to make a splashscreen and i have two different images...one for the background and other is for the logo.....both the images are in separate imageviews. The size of the images would be around 23kb and 3kb respectively. However when i run the app. It shows an error that processor maybe doing additional work. Skipping 88 frames. This completely skips the splashscreen and directly goes to main activity. Please can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: please post yout logcat , xml and java code

Answer (score 0):

set background image in parent and give logo image as a child...
like this :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundImage"
    tools:context="xyz.xyz.com.xyz.activity.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logoImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In java code use this :-

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private long ms = 0;
    private long splashTime = 2000;
    private boolean splashActive = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread mythread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                            if (!paused)
                                ms = ms + 100;
                            sleep(100);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        System.out.println("reached");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        System.out.println("reached1");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        System.out.println("reached2");
                        finish();
                        System.out.println("reached3");
                    }
                }
            };
            mythread.start();

}
```